# How to putFileAs with all backwards slashes?

Tags: laravel

How can I make `putFileAs` save the file with all backward slashes?

I use the following code:

```
Storage::disk('disk')->putFileAs(
            "\some_folder\\$year\\",
            $request->file('document'),
            "document.$extension"
        );
```

But it saves the path like so:

```
\some_folder\2023/document.pdf
```

but I want the last slash to also be backwards:

```
\some_folder\2023\document.pdf
```

How can I do that?

From what I saw, the code responsible for that is in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php`:

```
$result = $this->put($path = trim($path.'/'.$name, '/'), $stream, $options);
```

Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows? Windows uses backslashes, Linux uses forward slashes, and you really shouldn't try to change it

Comment: I'm using windows, that's why it's annoying that it still puts the forward slash